# Windows IIS 10 prompt and ask for credentials for anonymous website

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I'm having a weird issue in IIS 10. I have a website that is public facing website and hosted in AWS. The website can browse thru http, but when browse in https it's prompt to ask for credential. If I click on cancel will get 401 unauthorized.

The SSL is get from **win-acme.v2.1.6.773.x64.pluggable**

[Able to access in http](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HMN0.png)

[Cannot access in https](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZdUP.png)

[Given full control to Application Pool Identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PauVU.png)

[Given full control to Everyone as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6X4sV.png)

[Anonymous authentication is the only enabled and tried IUSR and Application Pool Identity also failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx9WL.png)

Comment: That error message comes from the web app itself, so no IIS setting can let it go away. You have to learn the web app and see how to get rid of it.

Comment: hi @LexLi, the prompt login is default browser confirm dialog which I can pretty confirm is not from the web app. anyway, i have found out the root cause is because i've installed the new Window Admin Center in server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured the issue is because of the newly installed Windows Admin Center and cause all the https (443) port route to Admin Center which redirect all the https to Admin Center site.

Do take not that after uninstall the Windows Admin Center, the 443 port is still reserved and cause the https get 503 error. There is another step to unreserved those 443 port by following https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103815/13356372 answer.